# How to list all packages in apple's conda channel?

Tags: python, conda

I know Apple provides tensorflow-metal on their `conda -c apple` channel.
How do I see the rest of the packages in that channel?

The "answers" I found online address finding a package to install, like `conda search *tensorflow*` but this is not what I want.
Instead, I would like to see what packages Apple has in their `-c apple` channel that I can install: in short "browse apple repository", a concept that I'm surprised is so difficult to achieve under conda...

p.s. I have tried `conda search -c apple` but it only lists all the packages from `conda-forge`, even after I did a `conda config --add channels apple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Web Browser

You can browse all packages in an Anaconda Cloud channel by visiting:

```
https://anaconda.org/<channel_name>/repo
```

For [the **apple** channel](https://anaconda.org/apple/repo), the `tensorflow-deps` package is the only package (right now).

### Conda CLI

Alternatively, one can also use `conda search` with something like:

```bash
$ conda search --override-channels -c apple '*'
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
tensorflow-deps                2.5.0               0  apple               
tensorflow-deps                2.5.0               1  apple               
tensorflow-deps                2.6.0               0  apple               
tensorflow-deps                2.7.0               0  apple
```

to list all packages. Note that the selector `*` must be escaped (`'*'`) otherwise the shell will interpret it.

### PyPI

The `tensorflow-macos` and `tensorflow-metal` packages are on PyPI, not Anaconda Cloud, and are uploaded by [user Kulin Seth](https://pypi.org/user/kulinseth/).

Comment: Appreciate your clarification and the link to the apple channel.